# How to retrieve query from a given parameter?

Tags: spring, rest, spring-boot

I've recently started learning Spring boot and Spring RESTful at work. I'm able to print "Hello world" in a spring REST project. I've also used collections and am able to display the names of cities. Now, I need to give the user the ability to request for a city, upon which the app will retrieve the data for that particular city only.

I know I have to use RequestMapping, but I can't seem to understand a lot of the technical jargon. This isn't a request for you to do my work, all I'm asking for is help. I would've learnt everything much better, but my company has given me less than a week to show it as a demo, and I've just learnt the basics of Spring, so I've got to learn on the go.

Any help is appreciated.

Instead of separate packages, I've placed them all in the main folder.

**This class provides the data for the request.**

```
package com.weatherreport.demo;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController

public class WeatherResource
{
    @RequestMapping("weather")

    public List<Weather> getWeather()
    {
        List<Weather> weather=new ArrayList<>();

        Weather a1=new Weather();
        Weather a2=new Weather();
        Weather a3=new Weather();
        Weather a4=new Weather();
        Weather a5=new Weather();
        Weather a6=new Weather();

        a1.setCity("Timbuktu");
        a1.setMaxTemp(38);
        a1.setMinTemp(15);
        a1.setRainfall(3.5);
        a1.setWindspeed((float) 11.5);
        a1.setHumidity(29);


        a2.setCity("London");
        a2.setMaxTemp(12);
        a2.setMinTemp(2);
        a2.setRainfall(12.5);
        a2.setWindspeed((float) 1.5);
        a2.setHumidity(12);




        a3.setCity("Delhi");
        a3.setMaxTemp(38);
        a3.setMinTemp(29);
        a3.setRainfall(0.2);
        a3.setWindspeed((float) 19.5);
        a3.setHumidity(9);


        a4.setCity("Mawsynram");
        a4.setMaxTemp(22);
        a4.setMinTemp(16);
        a4.setRainfall(358.5);
        a4.setWindspeed((float) 91.5);
        a4.setHumidity(96);


        a5.setCity("Wellington");
        a5.setMaxTemp(12);
        a5.setMinTemp(9);
        a5.setRainfall(31.5);
        a5.setWindspeed((float)44);
        a5.setHumidity(85);




        weather.add(a1);
        weather.add(a2);
        weather.add(a3);
        weather.add(a4);
        weather.add(a5);



        return weather;
    }


}
```

**This is a basic class defining the variables and their getters setters.**

```
package com.weatherreport.demo;

public class Weather
{
    private String city;
    private int maxTemp;
    private int minTemp;
    private float rainfall;
    private float windspeed;
    private int humidity;
    public String getCity() {
        return city;
    }
    public void setCity(String city) {
        this.city = city;
    }
    public int getMaxTemp() {
        return maxTemp;
    }
    public void setMaxTemp(int maxTemp) {
        this.maxTemp = maxTemp;
    }
    public int getMinTemp() {
        return minTemp;
    }
    public void setMinTemp(int minTemp) {
        this.minTemp = minTemp;
    }
    public float getRainfall() {
        return rainfall;
    }
    public void setRainfall(double d) {
        this.rainfall = (float) d;
    }
    public float getWindspeed() {
        return windspeed;
    }
    public void setWindspeed(float windspeed) {
        this.windspeed = windspeed;
    }
    public int getHumidity() {
        return humidity;
    }
    public void setHumidity(int humidity) {
        this.humidity = humidity;
    }



}
```

**No changes have been made to the SpringBootApplication class.**

Now, when I send a GET request through POSTman, I get all the data present in the collection. Instead, what I want is that I want to be able to give the user the ability to type in a city, check if the required city is in the database. If it is, it should show the data for that particular city only.

I understand this type of a question is frowned upon. But I'm stuck between a rock and a hard place and could use every little bit of help. Thanks.

**EDIT**

I finally did it. Googling and learning a bit on the way.

These were my requirements: I had to make some data in a collection. Then I had to retrieve the data of the city requested. I used the Web dependency, nothing more.

First, make a model class, define all of the required parameters in the model class. Check above for the said class.

I chose to do it the ugly way, not separating the repository and the control class. Anyway, here's the code for the control/resource class.

```
@RestController
public class WeatherResource
{

    @RequestMapping(value = "/weather", method = RequestMethod.GET) //This will get the entire data.
    public List getWeather()
    {
        List<Weather> listOfCityWeather = new ArrayList();
        listOfCityWeather=createCityWeatherList();
        return listOfCityWeather;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/weather/{city}", method = RequestMethod.GET) // Gets the data for a specific city
    public Weather getWeatherByCity(@PathVariable String city)
    {

        List<Weather> listOfCityWeather = new ArrayList();
        listOfCityWeather=createCityWeatherList();

        for (Weather weather: listOfCityWeather) {
            if(weather.getCity().equalsIgnoreCase(city))
            {

                return weather;

            }

        }


        return null;
    }



        public List createCityWeatherList()
        {

            List<Weather> listOfCityWeather=new ArrayList<>();

            Weather a1=new Weather();



            a1.setCity("Timbuktu");
            a1.setMaxTemp(38);
            a1.setMinTemp(15);
            a1.setRainfall(3.5);
            a1.setWindspeed((float) 11.5);
            a1.setHumidity(29);


            //Initialise the List as required. I have provided an example.


            listOfCityWeather.add(a1);


            return listOfCityWeather;
        }



}
```

Thanks to all, especially @g00glen00b for helping me.

Comment: So you did *print "Hello world" in a spring REST project* and you don't know what is `@RequestMapping` ?? How is that possible?

Comment: https://spring.io/guides

Comment: As I said, I've got very little time to create a service using REST. I just followed the instructions on YouTube videos. I need time to learn, which I certainly don't have. So I have to learn on the job.

Comment: Then you need to tell whoever set you the task that you don't have enough time. That doesn't make this a valid question for Stack Overflow.

Comment: [`@RequestMapping` javadoc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestMapping.html).

Comment: @g00glen00b: I've made a few changes. Hope the question meets the community standards now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, if you want to use a database you need to make a few changes to your codebase. If you're going to use a SQL database<sup>(1)</sup>, you could use [Spring Data JPA](https://projects.spring.io/spring-data-jpa/) and an in-memory database like HSQLDB or H2 for development/testing purposes. To use those, you need to add a few dependencies, for example using Maven:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId>
    <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

> <sup>(1)</sup> Even if you're not going to use a SQL database, the goal of the Spring Data project is to provide a consistent API for all datasources, so you would be able to change your code easily.

After that, you need to change your `Weather` class so that it's a valid JPA entity (an entity class is a Java representation of your table in your database). One thing you have to define here is your primary key, which should be unique. For example, in this case it could be the city:

```java
@Entity // Add this to declare your Weather class as an entity
public class Weather {
    @Id // Add this to define your city as the primary key
    private String city;
    private int maxTemp;
    private int minTemp;
    private float rainfall;
    private float windspeed;
    private int humidity;

    // Getters + Setters
}
```

Now that you have an entity, you can create a Spring data repository, which offers methods to access/modify data from your database. Spring Data will do most of this for you, all you have to do is to create a new interface that extends from `JpaRepository`:

```java
public interface WeatherRepository extends JpaRepository<Weather, String> {

}
```

> The generics passed to `JpaRepository<Weather, String>` are your entity class and the type of your primary key (which is your city, so it's a `String`).

After that you could move the logic you used to create all weather records so that they're created when you start your application. For this purpose, we can implement the `ApplicationRunner` interface:

```java
@Component
public class WeatherInitializer implements ApplicationRunner {
    private WeatherRepository repository;

    public WeatherInitializer(WeatherRepository repository) {
        this.repository = repository;
    }

    @Override
    public void run(ApplicationArguments args) {
        Weather a1=new Weather();
        Weather a2=new Weather();
        // Initialize the weather objects like you did in your controller

        // Save all weather records on startup
        repository.saveAll(Arrays.asList(a1, a2, a3, a4, a5));
    }
}
```

Spring will automatically create an instance of this class, inject the `WeatherRepository` and invoke the `run()` method when the application is started.

Now you can refactor your controller to use your repository:

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/weather") // All endpoints will have '/weather' in them, so you can put it here
public class WeatherResource {
    private WeatherRepository repository;

    public WeatherResource(WeatherRepository repository) {
        this.repository = repository;
    }

    @GetMapping // You can use GetMapping to only allow GET calls
    public List<Weather> getWeather() {
        return repository.findAll(); // This should replace your original implementation
    }
}
```

Now, for the parameterized call, you have to decide how you want to send those parameters, for example:

- You could use query parameters (like `/weather?city=Timbuktu`)
- You could use path parameters (like `/weather/Timbuktu`)
- ...

If you want to use path parameters, you could use the `@PathVariable` annotation. So for example, you could add this method to your `WeatherResource`:

```java
@GetMapping("/{city}")
public Weather getWeather(@PathVariable String city) {
    return repository.findById(city);
}
```

By using the `{city}` placeholder in our path and using the `@PathVariable` annotation, Spring will be able to pass the name of the city to your method. After that, you can use the `repository.findById()` method to fetch the weather for a specific city.

If you would prefer to use query parameters in stead, you don't need the `{city}` placeholder and you would have to replace the `@PathVariable` annotation by the `@RequestParam` annotation:

```java
@GetMapping
public Weather getWeather(@RequestParam String city) {
    return repository.findById(city);
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, man. You've been of great help. You've practically done the job for me. I'm try to learn as fast as I can. Would it be all right if I could post queries if any come up regarding this question in the comments? Thanks again

Comment: @Zer0 it depends on the query. If something is unclear in this answer, you can ask about it in the comments so that I can improve my answer where necessary. However, if it's a new question that has nothing to do with using query parameters, you should probably ask a new question. Stack Overflow is about asking small-scoped Q&A, so that problems can be solved "in isolation" and future readers can also be helped with it. That's a lot more difficult if solutions are hidden in the comments.

Comment: Also, be aware, this code is meant as a way to learn. This is certainly not production-ready copy-paste code.

Comment: I'm well aware of that. Your answer has given me a few pointers. I was able to make a rudimentary app work. Thanks!

Comment: @Zer0 Ok, that's great to hear! I was just slightly concerned because you said that I practically did the job for you, while there were certainly some things that had to be changed. But it looks like it wasn't necessary to be concerned then.